# Yii2 basic gridview just header and values

Tags: yii2, widget

I would like to show data of a joined query... (Controller):

```
$znw_a = Znw::find()->withA()->where(['znw.id' => $zg_id])->one();
...
return $this->render('create', [
    ...
    'znw_a' => $znw_a,
```

...like a very basic gridview, without pager, summary, etc, only the pure header with the data. The main idea is to show it like if it was a detailview simply transposed, so that I see data from left to right instead of top to bottom, so like a simple Excel table for example.

Is there such a simple widget like this in yii? Because GridView is not working like this, and before I'm trying to adjust my query in order to match the criteria of Gridview, maybe someone can give me a tip and I can achieve what I want easier. Can you please point me to the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just extend DetailView and make one that is displaying data like you want? Modify `$template` and `renderAttribute()` and Bjorn Stronginthearm is your uncle.

Comment: I'm going to check that out, but I'm not that professional I guess... :(

Comment: I will try to prepare something in a minute.

Comment: the simplest way is a gridview without pagination and without searcModel ..

Comment: With the query above, not really I guess, because it needs an ActiveDataProvider, and Totalcount and ... I've tried and faced a lot of error messages already :(

Comment: I've checked `$template` out, it makes sense, but it makes always a new line and I have no idea how to avoid that. It's for a single attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend DetailView for this one and use your class instead. Something like (assuming basic project template):

```
namespace app\widgets;

use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class MyDetailView extends DetailView
{
    public $template = '<td>{value}</td>';
    public $headerTemplate = '<th>{label}</th>';

    public function run()
    {
        $rows = [];
        $headers = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute) {
            list($row, $header) = $this->renderAttribute($attribute, $i++);
            $rows[] = $row;
            $headers[] = $header;
        }

        $options = $this->options;
        $tag = ArrayHelper::remove($options, 'tag', 'table');
        $topRow = Html::tag('tr', implode("\n", $headers));
        $dataRow = Html::tag('tr', implode("\n", $rows));
        echo Html::tag($tag, $topRow . $dataRow, $options);
    }

    protected function renderAttribute($attribute, $index)
    {
        if (is_string($this->template)) {
            $row = strtr($this->template, [
                '{value}' => $this->formatter->format($attribute['value'], $attribute['format']),
            ]);
        } else {
            $row = call_user_func($this->template, $attribute, $index, $this);
        }
        if (is_string($this->headerTemplate)) {
            $header = strtr($this->headerTemplate, [
                '{label}' => $attribute['label'],
            ]);
        } else {
            $header = call_user_func($this->headerTemplate, $attribute, $index, $this);
        }
        return [$row, $header];
    }
}
```

save it to `/widgets/MyDetailView.php`

Use it with

```
use app\widgets\MyDetailView;

<?= MyDetailView::widget([
    // ...
]) ?>
```

Comment: sorry, but do I have to define namespace also...?

Comment: Yes. Depending where you put this. Remember that in basic project root namespace is `app` and in advanced one it's `frontend`, `backend`, `common` or `console`.

Comment: if I put it in `yii2/widgets/` (I know it's not good, but just to try if I can make it work anyway) without namespace (then I guess it has to be like that) I'm getting `Cannot redeclare class`

Comment: You really need to read more about PHP, my friend. Anyway I'm assuming you have got basic template. Add namespace `app\widgets` in the class. Save it in `/widgets` folder as `MyDetailView.php`. Use it with namespace like `\app\widgets\MyDetailView::widget()`.

Comment: Yeah I know that and I'm trying to do my best. Basic template. Anyway, if I'm doing like you said, `Class 'app\widgets\yii\widgets\DetailView' not found`

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much! (Note: above the table there is an additional `<>><>>`)

Comment: It should be by default implemented in Yii2 as `DetailViewHorizontal`, or DetailView with the template option `Horizontal`. Megageil!

Comment: Just one more question: can I somehow change class to danger with this, or not. If not, absolutely no problem, I just would like to know. (because I've tried and it didn't work :) but probably because of me)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I would like eventually change background color. I've tried `'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'danger']`

Comment: The same options available in DetailView are available in extended class as well.

Comment: anyway, by me it's not working unfortunately. What am I missing eventually?

Comment: Start another question, extended discussions needs to be avoided here.